# How to make Line save pictures & videos to the SD card?

Tags: settings, sd-card, files, line

Line is the application taking up most place of my internal storage ; this is because it saves many profile pictures and chat videos, to the internal storage.
How can I tell it to save them to my SD card instead?

Answer (score -1):

1. Head into the Settings menu.
2. Scroll down to find “Apps“. Tap on it.
3. Now, you will observe the list of applications installed on your device.
4. Tap on any of the apps that you want to store on SD Card. ...
5. Scroll down, and you will find “Move to SD Card” option.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not move the saved pictures and videos from internal storage to the SD card.